# If $\frac{1}{8} \left(5^m-2\cdot 3^m+1\right)$ is prime, then $m=2p$ where $p$ is prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, congruences

The following statements are easy to prove with elementary arguments:

- $X_m=\frac{1}{8} \left(5^m-2\cdot3^m+1\right)$ is an integer for all
  integers $m\ge 0$
- ($m \equiv 0  \mod 4$  or $m \equiv 1  \mod 4$ )$\Longrightarrow$ 
  ($X_m \equiv 0  \mod 2$)
- ($m \equiv 3  \mod 4$  )$\Longrightarrow$($X_m \equiv 0  \mod 3$)
- ($m \equiv 6  \mod 12$  )$\Longrightarrow$($X_m \equiv 0  \mod 7$)
- ($m \equiv 10  \mod 20$  )$\Longrightarrow$($X_m \equiv 0  \mod 11$)
- ($m \equiv 6  \mod 20$  )$\Longrightarrow$($X_m \equiv 0  \mod 11$)
- ($X_m \equiv0  \mod 5$)$\Longrightarrow$($m\equiv0   \mod 2$ )
- $X_m$ is prime $\Longrightarrow$  $m=2k$ where $k$ is odd

Moreover, it seems that $X_{158}$ is prime.

> $ \frac{1}{8} \left(5^m-2\cdot 3^m+1\right)$ is prime $\Longrightarrow$
>   $m=2p$ where $p$ is prime

Is this true?

This would be analogous to $2^n-1$ is prime $\Longrightarrow$ $n$ is prime.

But here, I have doubts because sometimes when $7$ is the smallest odd prime factor of $\frac{m}{2}$, my numerical computations show me that the prime divisors of  $ \frac{1}{8} \left(5^m-2 \cdot 3^m+1\right)$ can be quite large.

EDIT 1.  Actually $7$ is the first prime which is not a Sophie Germain prime. If $m=2(2k+1)$ and $2k+1$ has a prime divisor $p$ such that $2p+1$ is also prime then it is easy to see that $2p+1$ divides $X_m$, so that $X_m$ cannot be prime.
The above conjecture then becomes :

> $ \frac{1}{8} \left(5^m-2\cdot 3^m+1\right)$ is prime $\Longrightarrow$
>   $m=2p$ where $p$ is prime but not a Sophie Germain prime

EDIT 2.  The same can be shown for the Stirling Number of 2nd kind $
{m+1\brace 3}=\frac{1}{2} \left(3^m-2\cdot2^m+1\right)$ and the corresponding conjecture would be

> $ {m+1\brace 3}$ is prime $\Longrightarrow$
>   $m=2p$ where $p$ is prime but not a Sophie Germain prime

But It seems that no $m$ is known yet for which $ {m+1\brace 3}$ is prime.

EDIT 3.
These numbers have a general form $$q_{m,k}=\frac{\underset{j=0}{\overset{k}{\Sigma }}(-1)^{k-j} (2 j+1)^m \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 k \\
 j \\
\end{array}
\right) }{2^k k!}$$
 From https://oeis.org/A028491 there are at least 18 known values of $m$ for which $q_{m,1}=\frac{3^m -1}{2}$ is prime.

So far we have 2 prime values for $X_m=q_{m,2}$

$q_{159,3}$ is prime and it remains to be checked whether other prime $q_{m,3}$ can be found for reasonnably small $m$
$$q_{m,3}=\frac{1}{48} \left(7^m-3.5^m+3.3^m-1\right)$$

In the same line 
$$ {m\brace k}=\frac{\underset{j=0}{\overset{k}{\Sigma }}(-1)^{k-j} j^m \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 k \\
 j \\
\end{array}
\right) }{k!}$$
For $k=2$, 44 of them are known to be prime (Mersenne primes)

For $k=3$, apparently none is known to be prime

For $k=4$, only 4 of them are known to be prime (https://oeis.org/A100958)

For $k\gt 4$, apparently none is known to be prime either.

These numbers grow with $m$ like $(2k+1)^m$ or $k^m$ : this is probably why they cannot be prime as often for large $k$ as for small $k$.

But it seems that being prime is more likely for $q_{m,k}$ than for $ {m\brace 2k+1}$, I wonder why...

Comment: $m=158$ and $m=6662$ are the only solutions for $m\le10^4$ so that $X_m$ is prime, and they are both of the form $2p$.

Comment: It would be nice if this were not just a coincidence. Is there a known factorisation for $x^m-2y^m+1$? like there is the cyclotomic factorisation for $x^m-1$?

Comment: No further primes upto $m=100,000$. Note, that for the two examples, $m-1$ is prime.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful : $$\frac{5^{m+1}-2\times 3^{m+1}+1}{8}=\sum_{j=1}^m \frac{5^j-3^j}{2}$$

Comment: @Peter; thanks for the numerical search.

Comment: @Peter;  would you do the same search for $$q_{m,3}=\frac{1}{48} \left(7^m-3.5^m+3.3^m-1\right)$$   It is prime for $m=3* 53$. It would be nice to find a second $m$ for which $q_{m,3}$ is prime, and see whether is also three times a prime...

Comment: @Rene Gy A first result for your second formula : No further prime upto $m=30,000$.

Comment: No further prime upto $m=61,800$ for the second formula.

Comment: No further prime upto $m=71,000$. I will stop here. Maybe someone continues the search :)